# Does Firebird support filtered indexes?

Tags: firebird

I am trying to create filtered indexes in Firebird but I cannot find it. Is it possible?

I mean indexes that use a portion of rows in the table. It exists in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Firebird 4.0 and earlier do not have filtered (or partial) indexes. There is an improvement ticket in the Firebird tracker:  [Partial Indexes (not partitioning) [CORE3384] #3750](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/3750) ([pull request](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/pull/7257)), which will become available in Firebird 5.0 (which is expected to be released somewhere in 2023).

See also the Firebird 5.0 documentation for [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref50/fblangref50-ddl-index.html#fblangref50-ddl-idx-create).

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Check this quote from this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133241

> In SQL Server (and maybe other RDBMS's?), this can be worked around
>   using Filtered Indexes. In SQL Server you would add a WHERE condition
>   onto the end of your index definition to say "apply this index only to
>   records with a Status <> 'Complete' ". Then any query using this
>   predicate will most likely use the index on the small amount of
>   records not set to 'Complete'. However, based on the documentation
>   here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-index.html,
>   **it does not look like Firebird supports filtered indexes.**
>
> **A workaround** is to put 'Complete' records in an ArchiveTickets table.
>   Create a table with the exact same definition (though without any auto
>   generated ID) as your Tickets table and maintain rows between them by
>   pushing 'Complete' records to the ArchiveTickets table. The Index on
>   your Tickets table will then be over a much smaller number of records
>   and be much higher performance. This will likely mean you will need to
>   change any reports etc that reference 'Complete' tickets to point to
>   the Archive table or perform a UNION across both Tickets and
>   ArchiveTickets. This will have the advantage of not only being fast,
>   but will also mean that you can create specific indexes for the
>   ArchiveTickets table to make it perform better for other queries (for
>   instance: Give me the average time to completion for complete tickets)
>   which are not needed on the Tickets table.