# Conditional unique index in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

In SQL Server I can do this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_MyTable_Reference]
    ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([Reference])
    WHERE [Expired] = 0
```

Is there an equivalent in Firebird?

Comment: Related: [Does Firebird support filtered indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486252/does-firebird-support-filtered-indexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Firebird does not have conditional (or partial) indexes (support is expected in Firebird 5.0, see also [Does Firebird support filtered indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486252/does-firebird-support-filtered-indexes) and  [Partial Indexes (not partitioning) [CORE3384] #3750](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/3750)).

I can think of two possible alternatives:

1. Use a unique computed index that stores `Reference` when `Expired` is 0 and `null` otherwise:

   ```sql
   create unique index "IX_MyTable_Reference" 
     on "MyTable" 
     computed by (iif("Expired" = 0, "Reference", null));
   ```

   This index will enforce the uniqueness, but can only be used as an index itself in queries that literally use `iif("Expired" = 0, "Reference", null) = <somevalue>`, which makes it more complicated and less intuitive to use as an index compared to a partial index (where you'd be able to use `"Expired" = 0 and "Reference" = <somevalue>`).
2. Use a trigger that populates a separate table that can enforce the uniqueness through a unique constraint (or index) and a trigger that removes the record on delete (or use a cascading foreign key constraint) or if the `Expired` value changes.

   This solution doesn't give the benefits of having the index when querying (except maybe by explicitly joining the additional table).

   Given the complexity of this solution, I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Other potential alternatives like using a check constraint or trigger to check the contents of the current table wouldn't prevent concurrent transactions from inserting duplicates, nor do you get the benefits of having a partial index.

Comment: Will FBSql allow duplicate nulls in a unique index then?

Comment: @PeterMorris Yes, assuming you're using Firebird 1.5 or higher; it is the behaviour that the SQL standard defines for unique constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your help!